# Transposing a 32x64 matrix

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

```
if(N == 64 && M == 32) {

    int i, j, C[M][M], CC[M][M], D[M][M], DD[M][M];

    // get left half of the matrix, and transpose
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
    squareblocktranspose(M, M, C, CC, 4);

    // get right half of the matrix, and transpose
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = M; j < N; j++) {
            D[i][j-M] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
    squareblocktranspose(M, M, D, DD, 4);

    // put transposed left half of the matrix as top half of new matrix
    for (i=0; i < M; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            B[i][j] = CC[i][j];
        }
    }

    // put transposed right half of the matrix as bottom half of the old matrix
    for (i=M; i<N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            B[i][j] = DD[i-M][j];
        }
    }
}
```

squareblocktranspose is a function that transposes any square matrix, and it is confirmed to work. However, when I try to test this function, it does not transpose the matrix successfully. What am I doing wrong here? My work is due in 13 minutes... This is just a last ditch effort at figuring out what is going wrong.

Comment: while declaring matrices `int i, j, C[M][M], CC[M][M], D[M][M], DD[M][M];` you are using size `M` and M is 32, so how it can take 64 values? It will be `32 x 32` matrix only.

Comment: If it doesn't do it successfully, what *does* it do?

Comment: Use `C[j][i] = A[i][j];` to get transpose simply.